# React material-ui tabs stacking content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented the material-ui react tabs as follows

```
   <Tabs onChange={(value) => props.changeTabListener(value)} value={props.currentTab} style={styles.tabs}>
    <Tab label="Tab 1" value={props.candidatesTab}>
        <div style={props.currentTab == 0 ? {display:'inline'} : {display:'none'}}>

            <WorksheetTableContainer/>
            <div style={fabStyle}>
                <FloatingActionButton style={iconPadding}>
                    <ContentClear/>
                </FloatingActionButton>
                <FloatingActionButton style={iconPadding}>
                    <ModeEdit/>
                </FloatingActionButton>
                <FloatingActionButton style={iconPadding}>
                    <ContentSave />
                </FloatingActionButton>
                <FloatingActionButton  >
                    <ArrowForward />
                </FloatingActionButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Tab>
    <Tab label="Tab 2" value={props.savedTakesTab}>
        <div style={props.currentTab == 1 ? {display:'inline'} : {display:'none'}}>

            <WorksheetTableContainer/>

            <div style={fabStyle}>
                <FloatingActionButton  >
                    <ArrowForward />
                </FloatingActionButton>
            </div>
        </div>

    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Which works for material-ui components.  However, the WorksheetTableComponent stacks itself on the first tab.  Ie:[image]

How can I have the content be on two separate tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring since Tab isn't programmed to handle children like that. Fortunately, the Tab `label` property accepts a node, so you could even pass the desired child that way:

```
<Tab
   value={props.savedTakesTab}
   label={
     <div style={props.currentTab == 1 ? {display:'inline'} : {display:'none'}}>

        <WorksheetTableContainer/>

        <div style={fabStyle}>
            <FloatingActionButton  >
                <ArrowForward />
            </FloatingActionButton>
        </div>
    </div>
   }
 />
```

If you still wanted the Tab2 label, you can simply set it within the child node. Hope that helps.